# React Jest: trigger 'addEventListener' 'message' from tests

Tags: reactjs, dom, jestjs, react-testing-library, postmessage

I have some code my React project which listens to a [message event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent).

```
const onMessage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log('On onMessage has been fired');
}

window.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
```

Does anyone know how I can trigger this event from my test suite? I have tried libraries such as [events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) and numerous things such as

```
test('Recieves message', async () => {
  //Some setup..

  //trigger the addEventListener('message')
  window.parent.postMessage('Hello', '*');  //doesn't work
  window.postMessage('Hello', '*'); //doesn't work
  const ee = new events.EventEmitter();
  ee.emit('Hello') //doesn't work

  //Some further tests...
})
```

Nothing seems to work. Please note I need to be careful with this test that I do not mock and overwrite all `addEventListener`. I still need the core code to do what is was intending to do. I simply need to trigger or emit a message event from my tests

Answer (score 11):

In case you want to create a `window.postMessage` event, you could just leverage the `fireEvent` `react-testing-library` api.

You test code will looks like :

```
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';


test('Recieves message', async () => {
  // Some setup..

  // trigger the addEventListener('message')
    fireEvent(
      window,
      new MessageEvent("message", { data: { foo: "bar" }, origin: "whatever.com" })
    )

  //Some further tests...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [8. queue-a-global-task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#posting-messages) and this [issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2245#issuecomment-392556153). There is a hack way, you need to flush the microtasks from message queue.

E.g.

`main.ts`:

```
const onMessage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log('On onMessage has been fired');
};

window.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
```

`main.test.ts`:

```
function flushMessageQueue(ms = 10) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
describe('68756255', () => {
  test('Recieves message', async () => {
    require('./main');
    window.postMessage('Hello', '*');
    await flushMessageQueue();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68756255/main.test.ts (9.111 s)
  ● Console

    console.log
      On onMessage has been fired

      at onMessage (examples/68756255/main.ts:2:11)


Test Suites: 1 skipped, 1 passed, 1 of 2 total
Tests:       2 skipped, 1 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.918 s
```