# window.dispatchEvent from test code does not trigger window.addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, addeventlistener, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I have below listener added for which I am trying to write test using Jest. However, it seems as though the event I'm dispatching doesn't reach my code.

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'abc') {
      console.log(event.data.payload);
    }
});
```

I have tried below 2 approaches and both of them don't seem to work. I'm unable to verify the call using the spy object I'm creating. Please refer to the code below:

1. ```
    const listenerSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'addEventListener');

    const data = {
      type: 'abc',
      payload: '',
    };

    const messageEvent = new MessageEvent('message', {data});

    window.dispatchEvent(messageEvent);

    expect(listenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   ```
2. ```
   const listenerSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'addEventListener');

   const data = {
     type: 'abc',
     payload: '',
   };

   window.postMessage(data, '*');

   expect(listenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   ```

For the 1st approach, have also tried using 'new Event('message')'.

With above 2 approaches, I get the error as below:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

  102 |     window.dispatchEvent(messageEvent);
  103 |
> 104 |     expect(listenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      |                         ^
```

I have also tried to follow different websites including below:
https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953
https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/426

But no luck there as with typescript, I cannot follow the solution given. I have also tried to find answers on stackoverflow, but the none of solutions suggested seem to work for me.

I am new to react and got stuck with this. Any pointers on this would help.

Answer (score 1):

`jsdom` fire the `message` event inside a `setTimeout`, see [this](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/19.0.0/lib/jsdom/living/post-message.js#L36)

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  fireAnEvent("message", this, MessageEvent, { data: message });
}, 0);
```

For more info, see [issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2245#issuecomment-392556153)

So, it's asynchronous and you need to wait for the macro task scheduled by `setTimeout` to be finished before the test case ends.

`index.ts`:

```
export function main() {
  window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'abc') {
      console.log(event.data.payload);
    }
  });
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { main } from './';

function flushMessageQueue(ms = 10) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

describe('71912032', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    main();
    const data = { type: 'abc', payload: 'xyz' };

    window.postMessage(data, '*');

    await flushMessageQueue();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('xyz');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71912032/index.test.ts
  71912032
    ✓ should pass (41 ms)

  console.log
    xyz

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:845:25)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.01 s, estimated 13 s
```

Also, take a look at this question [React Jest: trigger 'addEventListener' 'message' from tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756255/react-jest-trigger-addeventlistener-message-from-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at this discussion? It seems to have a similar requirement.
[Dispatch a Custom Event and test if it was correctly triggered (React TypeScript, Jest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400540/dispatch-a-custom-event-and-test-if-it-was-correctly-triggered-react-typescript)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).